# Can I get linear graph for reputation history?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

In profile control panel there is history of reputation but it is hardly readable. Could you insert there linear chart too?

Comment: How about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234414/158100)?

Comment: @rene Yes, I just must find out how to use it.

Comment: [Here you go](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203302/user-reputation-history?uid=1123020#graph)!

Comment: How about your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1138466/yoda?tab=reputation) reputation tab?